# Sending mail through http proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, smtpclient, http-proxy

I'm trying to send emails from a system that connects to internet through a http proxy which is set in Internet Options.

i'm using SmtpClient.

Is there any way to send mails with SmtpClient through this proxy setting.
Thanks

Comment: @Anthony, I believe he is referring the SmtpClient class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you want to use the browsers default settings, i would also like an answer for that.

Meanwhile, you could do it manually.

```
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@mailserver.com");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@mailserver.com");

    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to);
    mm.Subject = "Subject"
    mm.Body = "Body";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("proxy.mailserver.com", 8080);
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@mailserver.com", "password");

    client.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 7):

Http Proxies control http traffic, they rarely have anything to do with SMTP at all.  I've never heard of proxying SMTP before after all SMTP itself is intrinsically supports a chain of "proxies" to the destination SMTP server.

Comment: You could proxy SMTP to say a spam filter. Where the spam filter would evaluate the email and forward it on to the SMTP server.

Comment: @Charles:  Like I said in the answer STMP is intrinsically a series of "proxies" to the destination.   A spam filter is simply another SMTP server in the chain.

Comment: I believe it is possible.
Clever components implemented one:
http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuitenet/smtpclientnet.asp
but it doesn't seem worth buying it

Answer (score 3):

### Use MailKit

[From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> Important
>
> We don't recommend that you use the **SmtpClient** class for new
> development because **SmtpClient** doesn't support many modern protocols.
> Use [**MailKit**](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or other libraries instead. For more information, see
> [SmtpClient shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) on GitHub.

Create a console app and add MailKit

```
dotnet new console --framework net6.0
dotnet add package MailKit
```

Code to send through proxy

```
using MailKit.Net.Proxy;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

var emailFromAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";
var token = "mytoken";
var to = "Someone.Else@gmail.com";

var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Me", emailFromAddress));
message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(to));
message.Subject = "test";

message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = @"This is a test."
};

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.ProxyClient = new HttpProxyClient("my-proxy.mydomain.com", 80);   // <-- set proxy
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    client.Authenticate(emailFromAddress, token);

    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

In this example, I've used Gmail to send the email. To do so you have to generate a token.
Go to your [gmail](https://mail.google.com/) > click on your icon on the very top right of the page > **Manage your Google Account** > from the menu on the left choose **Security** > half way down choose **App Passwords** > select **Mail** and select your device > press **Generate** > copy the token and replace mytoken above.

Answer (score 0):

If the only access you have to the internet is through HTTP, then pretty much the only way you'll be able to do this is by setting up a VPS (or equiv) with SSH on port 443 and using corkscrew (or putty) to tunnel ssh through. From there it is a simple matter to forward smtp traffic over your ssh tunnel.

Be aware that you may be violating the companies computing policy if you do this.